# Android media player unable to play RTSP stream throwing error (100, 0)

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview, rtsp, wowza

I am trying to play rtsp stream with the video view :-

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HEADER_BLOCK = true;
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_view);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Opening video...", true);
        mediaController = new MediaController(VideoStreamingActivity.this);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(streamerUrl));
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                videoView.start();
                startTime = startTime * 60000;
                videoView.seekTo(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(startTime).substring(0, String.valueOf(startTime).indexOf("."))));
                mediaController.show();
            }
        });

        videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if(what==1 && extra==-1){
                    Toast.makeText(VideoStreamingActivity.this,
                            "Sorry!! unable to play the video since the video not compatible with your android player.", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(VideoStreamingActivity.this,
                            "Unable to play selected video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                VideoStreamingActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

the 'streamerUrl' is proper rtsp url generated from wowza server...but in the logcat i am getting following error.

```
04-02 09:22:41.476: D/VideoView(9178): onMeasure()
04-02 09:22:41.476: I/VideoView(9178):     Setting size: 320x221
04-02 09:22:41.484: D/VideoView(9178): onMeasure()
04-02 09:22:41.484: I/VideoView(9178):     Setting size: 320x221
04-02 09:22:41.546: V/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(9178): HTTP Response Code: 200
04-02 09:22:41.578: I/MediaPlayer(9178): path is null
04-02 09:22:41.578: D/MediaPlayer(9178): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-02 09:22:41.679: D/VideoView(9178): onMeasure()
04-02 09:22:41.679: I/VideoView(9178):     Setting size: 320x221
04-02 09:22:41.679: D/VideoView(9178): onMeasure()
04-02 09:22:41.679: I/VideoView(9178):     Setting size: 320x221
04-02 09:22:50.210: W/AudioSystem(9178): AudioFlinger server died!
04-02 09:22:50.210: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(9178): media server died
04-02 09:22:50.210: E/MediaPlayer(9178): error (100, 0)
04-02 09:22:50.210: E/MediaPlayer(9178): Error (100,0)
04-02 09:22:50.210: D/VideoView(9178): Error: 100,0
```

Can anyone tell whats happening?

Comment: Did you find a solution to the Error 100?

Answer (score 0):

remember to add internet access permission in manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

could you test rtsp video stream by trying:

```
rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov
```

if it still doesn't work, please let me know what't the problem